Lifting Galois groups to Witt vectors
Let $L/K$ be an arbitrary finite Galois extension of fields. This induces an injection of Cohen-Witt rings $W_C(K) \to W_C(L)$. Cohen-Witt rings are a generalization of Witt rings - in general they are a subring of the ring of Witt vectors. They are strict p-rings and in particular they are DVR's. When $k$ is perfect, the Cohen-Witt ring is just the ring of Witt vectors.
By functoriality, the Galois group $G = Gal(L/K)$ injects into the group $Aut(k(W_C(L))/k(W_C(K)))$ of automorphisms of $k(W_C(L))$ fixing $k(W_C(K))$, as fraction fields. Is it true that this realizes $G$ as the Galois group $Gal(k(W_C(L))/k(W_C(K)))$?
A reference for Cohen-Witt rings is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.08297, especially the construction in Section 7. Let $B \subset K$ be a $p$-basis. That is, $K = K^p(B)$ with some additional independence condition on $B$. Then define $C_{n+1}(K) = W_{n+1}(K^{(p^{n})})([B])$ where $[B]$ denotes the set of elements $\{(b,0, \dotsc ) : b \in B\}$. Set $W_C(K) = \lim_n C_n(K)$ as the inverse limit. Once you show that a Galois extension preserves $p$-bases, it follows that this construction is functorial.
I need to carry out Galois descent for some objects over Cohen-Witt rings. Is there any reference for this? Would this result be true for ordinary rings of Witt vectors? It is certainly true for finite fields, as in this case we get unramified cyclic extensions which have no inertia.

Does $k(\cdot)$ mean the field of fractions?

@LSpice yes this is the field of fractions

What is your source for Cohen-Witt rings?

Is $W_C(K)$ functorial in $K$ for imperfect $K$?

@PiotrAchinger See Theorem 6.2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.08297

@S.Carnahan I think https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.08297 is pretty good but it's hard to find sources on this topic, which is surprising as I'm sure some people may want to lift to a characteristic 0 DVR when working over imperfect fields.
